# Clustering: choosing correlation-based over euclidean distance (fviz_dist)

Tags: r, correlation, clustering, euclidean

I'm trying to cluster some business data. You can imagine the data as describing customers (age, no. of purchases, satisfaction after the first purchase, etc.). I work with normalised data. I also discarded highly correlated variables beforehand.

I visualised three samples from the data (the data is huge and R can't handle the whole dataset simultaneously) twice: 1) based on the default euclidean distance and 2) based on the correlation-based (Pearson) distance. I used fviz_dist to do that.

The result of visualising 3 different samples with fviz_dist using the two methods is:

- for the Euclidean distance, I received 3 totally different plots (the pattern of red and blue squares is completely different for every sample)
- for the correlation-based distance, the plots are so similar that I needed to check again whether I didn't use the same sample three times (I didn't).

My questions are:

1. Does the result mean that the correlation-based distance is better for this data set?
2. Does it suggest that hierarchical clustering methods can be expected to be better than kmeans/pam for this data set?

I've been searching for more info about correlation-based distance, but most of it seems to be related to biological sciences and DNA. Therefore, I'm not sure how to interpret my result.

Comment: Uniform random data also looks similar, so that does not guatantee quality.... So no, the little information you gave means neither, but also does not imply the opposite. It's just speculation.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse, I think I understand why the visualisations for Euclidean and Pearson's corr were so different. I used exactly the same tf for both, with variables in cols, just changed this one analysis parameter. Acc to what I read yesterday, Pearson's corr as a distance/similarity measure is suitable to compare cases/ samples, not variables. If R doesn't do transposing itself, I should have done it for the Pearson's correlation analysis. This would also explain why the 3 visualisations for pearson's were so incredibly similar: they analysed normalised variables.

Comment: Pearson can be used both in rows and columns, so you need to be explicit which version to use. It also has a built-in normalization, so linear scaling won't affect Pearson (if both done along the same axis). Don't blindly normalize, as it can discard valuable information.